# How to run a golang function call once per key parameter in concurrent environment?

Tags: go, concurrency

This example seems to fetch data once, but I don't think it will invoke a `fetchDataInBackground` function in background for each `key` concurrently.

```
func Get(key string){
    ...
    if itIsTheTimeToRefreshData{
         var once sync.Once
         onceBody := func() {
            fetchDataInBackground()
         }
         go func() {
            once.Do(onceBody)
         }()
     }
     ...
 }
```

what I need to do is to assign each `Once` instance to a `key` so that all fetch data for different keys can be done concurrently.
how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `sync.Once` is not well for such task. You need to maintain some flag ("once") for each key individually. Map with mutexed access is one of possible solutions.

Full working example:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "sync"
        "time"
)

var once map[string]bool
var onceMutex sync.Mutex
var itIsTheTimeToRefreshData = true

func Get(key string) {
        fmt.Printf("Access for key: %s\n", key)
        if itIsTheTimeToRefreshData {
                onceBody := func() {
                        fmt.Printf("Only once for key: %s\n", key)
                        //fetchDataInBackground()
                }

                onceMutex.Lock()
                if !once[key] { // is it first time?
                        once[key] = true
                        onceMutex.Unlock()

                        // refresh something here
                        go onceBody()
                } else {
                        onceMutex.Unlock()
                }
        }
}

func main() {
        once = make(map[string]bool)

        // do it first time in parallel
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
                key := fmt.Sprintf("i%d", i)
                go func(key string) {
                        Get(key)
                }(key)
        }
        // and another time
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
                key := fmt.Sprintf("i%d", i)
                go func(key string) {
                        Get(key)
                }(key)
        }
        fmt.Println("All requested.")
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
}
```